# Video rotated after applying AVVideoComposition

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, cifilter, avvideocomposition

After applying an `AVVideoComposition` to my `AVPlayerItem`, the filter I apply does work, but the video gets rotated in the `AVPlayerLayer`.

I know for a fact that the problem is not with the filtered frame because if I show the frame in a `UIImageView`, the frame is rendered 100% correctly.

The video shows correctly *until* I apply a `videoComposition`. Setting the `videoGravity` on the `AVPlayerLayer` does not help.

The video gets rotated 90º clockwise and gets stretched in the layer.

Essentially, the video is displayed perfectly in the `AVPlayerLayer` before the `AVPlayerItem` is fed through the `AVMutableVideoComposition`. Once that happens, the video is rotated -90º, and then scaled to fit the same dimensions as the video before filtering. This suggests to me that it does not realize that its transform is already correct, and so it is reapplying the transform on itself.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Here is some code:

```
private func filterVideo(with filter: Filter?) {
    if let player = player, let playerItem = player.currentItem {
        let composition = AVMutableComposition()
        let videoAssetTrack = playerItem.asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first
        let videoCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
        try? videoCompositionTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: kCMTimeZero, duration: playerItem.asset.duration), of: videoAssetTrack!, at: kCMTimeZero)
        videoCompositionTrack?.preferredTransform = videoAssetTrack!.preferredTransform

        let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition(asset: composition, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: { (request) in
            let filteredImage = <...>
            request.finish(with: filteredImage, context: nil)
        })

        playerItem.videoComposition = videoComposition
    }
}
```

Comment: is your videoComposition custom or you are using `AVVideoComposition(_:, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:)?

Comment: @Tiko, I use `applyingCIFiltersWithHandler`

Comment: Try to remove line: videoCompositionTrack?.preferredTransform = videoAssetTrack!.preferredTransform

Comment: @ninjaproger, that makes the video disappear, although it weirdly works for some videos only some of the time. Sometimes it makes the video pause and not get the filter.

Comment: @IHaveAQuestion is this just happening with vertical or horizontal videos, or both? Test that out and let me know.

Comment: @impression7vx it actually seems to happen only with one video specifically. Any reason why this might happen? [This question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44962234/7214321) asks this if you can help.

Comment: Hey there! Did you solved it? Me and my team stuck in the same issue...

Comment: @RoiMulia, check out my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for me at the end:

```
private func filterVideo(with filter: Filter?) {
    guard let player = playerLayer?.player, let playerItem = player.currentItem else { return }

    let videoComposition = AVVideoComposition(asset: playerItem.asset, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: { (request) in
        if let filter = filter {
            if let filteredImage = filter.filterImage(request.sourceImage) {
                let output = filteredImage.cropping(to: request.sourceImage.extent)
                request.finish(with: output, context: nil)
            } else {
                printError("Image not filtered")
                request.finish(with: RenderError.couldNotFilter)
            }
        } else {
            let output = request.sourceImage.cropping(to: request.sourceImage.extent)
            request.finish(with: output, context: nil)
        }
    })

    playerItem.videoComposition = videoComposition
}
```

This is the `filterImage` function of `Filter`, which is just a nice little wrapper for `CIFilter`:

```
func filterImage(_ ciImage: CIImage) -> CIImage? {
    guard let filter = ciFilter else { return nil }
    filter.setDefaults()
    filter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    guard let filteredImageData = filter.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage else { return nil }
    return filteredImageData
}
```

Comment: Hey there, Does using the code above the rotation doesn't happening?

Comment: It's still rotating :\

Comment: @RoiMulia, is the video recorded by the device?

Answer (score 8):

You  have a problem in the renderingSize of `AVVideoComposition`. You should apply transform on `AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction` (ie. `Rotate`  and `translate`  transform ).

I have done it in **Objective-c** and am posting my code. You can convert the syntax into **Swift**

**Objective-c**

```
//------------------------------------
//      FIXING ORIENTATION
//------------------------------------


AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction * MainInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
MainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeAdd(firstAsset.duration, secondAsset.duration));

AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *FirstlayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:secondTrack]; // second

AVAssetTrack *FirstAssetTrack = [[firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
UIImageOrientation FirstAssetOrientation_  = UIImageOrientationUp;
BOOL  isFirstAssetPortrait_  = NO;
CGAffineTransform firstTransform = FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform;
if(firstTransform.a == 0 && firstTransform.b == 1.0 && firstTransform.c == -1.0 && firstTransform.d == 0)  {FirstAssetOrientation_= UIImageOrientationRight; isFirstAssetPortrait_ = YES;}
if(firstTransform.a == 0 && firstTransform.b == -1.0 && firstTransform.c == 1.0 && firstTransform.d == 0)  {FirstAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationLeft; isFirstAssetPortrait_ = YES;}
if(firstTransform.a == 1.0 && firstTransform.b == 0 && firstTransform.c == 0 && firstTransform.d == 1.0)   {FirstAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationUp;}
if(firstTransform.a == -1.0 && firstTransform.b == 0 && firstTransform.c == 0 && firstTransform.d == -1.0) {FirstAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationDown;}
CGFloat FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio = 320.0/FirstAssetTrack.naturalSize.width;
if(isFirstAssetPortrait_){
    FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio = 320.0/FirstAssetTrack.naturalSize.height;
    CGAffineTransform FirstAssetScaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio,FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio);
    [FirstlayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform, FirstAssetScaleFactor) atTime:kCMTimeZero];
}else{
    CGAffineTransform FirstAssetScaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio,FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio);
    [FirstlayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform, FirstAssetScaleFactor),CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 160)) atTime:kCMTimeZero];
}
[FirstlayerInstruction setOpacity:0.0 atTime:firstAsset.duration];



AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *SecondlayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:firstTrack];
AVAssetTrack *SecondAssetTrack = [[secondAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
UIImageOrientation SecondAssetOrientation_  = UIImageOrientationUp;
BOOL  isSecondAssetPortrait_  = NO;
CGAffineTransform secondTransform = SecondAssetTrack.preferredTransform;
if(secondTransform.a == 0 && secondTransform.b == 1.0 && secondTransform.c == -1.0 && secondTransform.d == 0)  {SecondAssetOrientation_= UIImageOrientationRight; isSecondAssetPortrait_ = YES;}
if(secondTransform.a == 0 && secondTransform.b == -1.0 && secondTransform.c == 1.0 && secondTransform.d == 0)  {SecondAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationLeft; isSecondAssetPortrait_ = YES;}
if(secondTransform.a == 1.0 && secondTransform.b == 0 && secondTransform.c == 0 && secondTransform.d == 1.0)   {SecondAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationUp;}
if(secondTransform.a == -1.0 && secondTransform.b == 0 && secondTransform.c == 0 && secondTransform.d == -1.0) {SecondAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationDown;}
CGFloat SecondAssetScaleToFitRatio = 320.0/SecondAssetTrack.naturalSize.width;
if(isSecondAssetPortrait_){
    SecondAssetScaleToFitRatio = 320.0/SecondAssetTrack.naturalSize.height;
    CGAffineTransform SecondAssetScaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(SecondAssetScaleToFitRatio,SecondAssetScaleToFitRatio);
    [SecondlayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(SecondAssetTrack.preferredTransform, SecondAssetScaleFactor) atTime:firstAsset.duration];
}else{
    ;
    CGAffineTransform SecondAssetScaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(SecondAssetScaleToFitRatio,SecondAssetScaleToFitRatio);
    [SecondlayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(SecondAssetTrack.preferredTransform, SecondAssetScaleFactor),CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 160)) atTime:secondAsset.duration];
}


MainInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:SecondlayerInstruction,nil];;

AVMutableVideoComposition *MainCompositionInst = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
MainCompositionInst.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:MainInstruction];
MainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
MainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 480.0);


// Now , you have Orientation Fixed Instrucation layer
// add this composition to your video 
// If you want to export Video than you can do like below

NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory()
stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *myPathDocs = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"final_merged_video-%d.mp4",arc4random() % 1000]];


NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];
// 5 - Create exporter
AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition
presetName:AVAssetExportPreset640x480];
exporter.outputURL=url;
exporter.videoComposition=MainCompositionInst;
exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
{

[[AppDelegate Getdelegate] hideIndicator];

[self exportDidFinish:exporter];
});
}];
```

for **Swift**
see this answer [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34617864/4466607)

in addition you can also try to rotate your video layer by applying rotation transform on it.

```
#define degreeToRadian(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0)

[_playerLayer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreeToRad‌​ian(degree))]
```

Comment: Setting the `videoInstruction` to the `videoComposition` makes the composition's handler not call. I'm guessing that I'm missing something obvious. Any ideas? This is driving me nuts!

Comment: Also, I am not trying to combine videos: I am trying to filter one single asset.

Comment: Please please please help!! I would ***love*** to be able to award you the bounty!!!

Comment: the Whole Video is Streched or Some assets is have this problem ??, if all the video is Streched than you can rotate your Video by your desired angle of degree

`[_playerLayer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreeToRadian(degree))];`  @IHaveAQuestion

Comment: where degree to Radian is `#define degreeToRadian(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0)`

Comment: also see this for more help , same like my answer but more explained https://abdulazeem.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/video-manipulation-in-ios-resizingmerging-and-overlapping-videos-in-ios/

Comment: Dhiru, unfortunately this did not work because when I set the instruction to the video composition, the video composition's handler is not called, which means that the video does not filter.

Comment: In addition to ^, setting a layer transform does not solve the scaling problem.

Comment: In your code, where to do the rotate? Can you provide an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If You are trying to play `AVMutableCompostion` You should set `AVAssetTrack`'s `preferredTransform` to `AVMutableCompositionTrack`'s `preferredTransform`.

```
let asset = AVAsset(url: url!)

let composition = AVMutableComposition()
let compositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

let videoTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).first

try? compositionTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration), of: videoTrack!, at: kCMTimeZero)

compositionTrack.preferredTransform = (videoTrack?.preferredTransform)!

let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: composition)
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorInvert")
playerItem.videoComposition = AVVideoComposition(asset: composition, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: { (request: AVAsynchronousCIImageFilteringRequest) in
            filter?.setValue(request.sourceImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            request.finish(with: (filter?.outputImage)!, context: nil)
        })
 .... the rest of code
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. The video is still messed up

Comment: Can you try to create `AVVideoComposition` with asset of `AVPlayerItem`, e.g. not to create `AVMutableComposition`, AVMutableVideoComposition(asset: playerItem.asset, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler ...

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. Oddly enough, it works perfectly for some videos but not for others.

Comment: A bizzarre thing is happening: most videos will filter perfectly, but once I try to filter a video that then disappears, *no* video will work –– including ones that worked before. The view controller is reinstantiated from scratch every time, so I have no idea why this would happen. Do you have any idea?

Comment: What do you mean that video disappears?

Comment: Which OS version are you using?

Comment: The video becomes invisible, but the sound still plays. This is iOS 11 beta. I am not sure if it's a bug though or if that is behavior that is continuing.

Comment: can You try it with iOS 10?

Comment: or maybe the problem is in filter, can you try it with CIFilter?

Comment: It is CIFilter, Filter is just my custom wrapper class

Comment: I mean to try with a native filter

Comment: I thought CIFilter was the native filter?

Comment: Didn't your write a custom kernel?

Comment: No I used the prewritten ones `("CIPhotoEffectChrome", "CIPhotoEffectNoir", ...)`

Comment: There have been [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45036171/video-ios-11-xcode-9#comment77047008_45036171) problems with video playback in iOS 11.

Comment: @AllenHumphreys, bug report submitted. Hopefully they listen :) They really need better documentation on this though!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of assuming that the image will be filtered, check first if `filteredImage` is `nil`. If not, then `request.finish(with: filteredImage, context: nil)`

However, if it is `nil` you must `request.finish(with: SomeError)`

This is as per the docs.

Answer (score -2):

Try this code below which worked for me

```
// Grab the source track from AVURLAsset for example.
let assetV = YourAVASSET.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).last

// Grab the composition video track from AVMutableComposition you already made.
let compositionV = YourCompostion.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).last

// Apply the original transform.
if ((assetV != nil) && (compostionV != nil)) {
    compostionV?.preferredTransform = (assetV?.preferredTransform)!
}
```

And then go ahead an export your video...

Comment: Cannot assign to property: 'preferredTransform' is a get-only property