# AVMutableVideoComposition request sourceImage is sometimes empty

Tags: ios, swift, image, avfoundation, cifilter

This is sort of an extension of [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44911802/7214321), but I think it is different enough to merit its own question:

I am filtering videos of various sizes, scales, etc. by feeding them into an `AVMutableVideoComposition`.

This is the code that I currently have:

```
private func filterVideo(with filter: Filter?) {
    if let player = playerLayer?.player, let playerItem = player.currentItem {
        let composition = AVMutableComposition()
        let videoAssetTrack = playerItem.asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first
        let videoCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
        try? videoCompositionTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: kCMTimeZero, duration: playerItem.asset.duration), of: videoAssetTrack!, at: kCMTimeZero)

        let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition(asset: composition, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: { (request) in
           print(request.sourceImage.pixelBuffer) // Sometimes => nil
           if let filter = filter {
                if let filteredImage = filter.filterImage(request.sourceImage) {
                    request.finish(with: filteredImage, context: nil)
                } else {
                    request.finish(with: RenderError.couldNotFilter)
                }
            } else {
                request.finish(with: request.sourceImage, context: nil)
            }
        })
        playerItem.videoComposition = videoComposition
    }
}
```

`filter` is an instance of my custom `Filter` class, which has functions to filter a UIImage or CIImage.

The problem is that some videos get messed up. This is the case for only the problematic videos for which `filteredImage => nil` as well. This suggests that some images are empty: their `pixelBuffer`s are `nil`. By the way, the `pixelBuffer` is `nil` *before* I even feed it into the `filter`.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you add a statement after you declare filteredImage - if(filteredImage == nil) { print(request.sourceImage) } so you can see if the actual sourceImage is nil? This will verify that your assumption of the pixelbuffer being nil

Comment: @impression7vx, that is actually exactly how I found out that `sourceImage == nil`

Comment: Can you post your Filter file so we can see what filterImage does? I can't provide any more specific help past that.

Comment: @impression7vx, I don't think that's the problem because `sourceImage.pixelBuffer` is `nil` even before I feed it into `filter`. I can add in the filter code if you recommend though?

Comment: Please tell me you found a solution. This drives me crazy!