# video iOS 11/ xcode 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I use this code to start a video (not full screen). People can press the **'full screen'** button to switch to full screen. However in iOS 11 beta the video turns black in full screen and I can't reverse it or get it playing again.

Is there an easy fix to update my code for iOS 11? Or does anyone know where to find a sample for this. I searched, but didn't find anything yet. 
Thanks a lot, Meg

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

       [super viewDidLoad];

    // grab a local URL to our video
    NSURL *videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"pres 2" withExtension:@"m4v"];

    // create an AVPlayer
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];

    // create a player view controller
    self.controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
    controller.player = player;
    [player play];


    // show the view controller
    [self addChildViewController:controller];
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
    controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,25, 750, 422);

}


-(void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *) notification{
    //remove the player

}


-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [controller.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:nil];
}

-(void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [controller.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:nil];

}
```

Comment: My first instinct is that it is either a bug in iOS 11 or it is the fact that you aren't doing the correct thing to add a child view controller, especially if you're using autolayout. You need to call `didMoveToParentViewController:` after you call `addChildViewController:`. It's in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621405-didmovetoparentviewcontroller?language=objc)

Comment: thanks for your quick response. I will look into this :-)

Comment: @user1737746 have you figured this out? I see exactly the same in my project. It seems worth reporting a bug with Apple :(

Comment: No, I still didn't figure this out. Tried lots of things. I'm just not sure about it being a bug. Maybe we should use player layer instead of subview. Will file a report with apple, just in case. Shall we be in touch through this post if either of us figures this out? Thanks ;-)

Comment: @Oliver Hu Problem solved!! See my post :-)

Answer (score 1):

@Oliver Hu 
Hi Oliver, got a very kind answer from Apple. Its not a bug, but a missing line in the code. Also the call Allen mentioned earlier should be added to the viewdidload! Here is Apple's answer:

if you need to teardown when the view controller is dismissed but not deallocated, you should wrap the calls in -[UIViewController isBeingDismissed], like so:

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

   [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

   if ([self isBeingDismissed])
  {
   [controller.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:nil];
   }
}

-(void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

   [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
   if ([self isBeingDismissed])
  {
   [controller.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:nil];
   }    
}
```

Also you should call `[controller didMoveToParentViewController:self]` when embedding it.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!! I do think it is a regression in Apple's code.. I worked around this by setting the `addChildViewController` in viewDidLoad and call `addSubview` in viewWillAppear.